# Permissions on WINDOWS environment variables

Tags: windows

Supposing a service that is running with administrator privileges creates an environment variable.

Can a user with non-admin privileges read this environment variable?

If so, is there a way to restrict the environment variable?

Comment: No;  Environment variable can be read by any user.  That is the entire point of them.

Comment: @Ramhound "System variables are shared for all users, but user variables are only for your account/profile."

Comment: @DavidPostill - Well sure; But those (user) system variables literally don't exist for other users.  Suppose I was strictly speaking about system variables not (user) system variables

Comment: Depends on where the environment variable is created. If the service creates an environment variable only in its own process, then that would not be readable to other users (at least, not without sufficient permissions). If the service creates a system-wide environment variable, processes created by any user would automatically inherit the variable. So it really depends on what you mean.